# Bjacc/j if and while definition

Tags: java, yacc

So I have a problem with if then else and while definition in byacc/j. Can somebody helps? input.y is below. I cannot understand the yacc errors. So It's clear that 12 rules never reduced but what I shoud do?

```
%{
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
%}

/* YACC Declarations */
%token NUM
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%left NEG /* negation--unary minus */
%right '^' /* exponentiation */
%token IF ELSE WHILE EXIT
%token EQ LE GE NE
%token STRING NUM ID

%%

PROGRAM: OPS
;

OPS:    OP
|       OPS OP
;

OP1:    '{' OPS '}'
|       EXPR ';'
|       IF '(' EXPR ')' OP1 ELSE OP1
|       WHILE '(' EXPR ')' OP1
|       EXIT ';'
;

OP2:    IF '(' EXPR ')' OP
|       IF '(' EXPR ')' OP1 ELSE OP2
|       WHILE '(' EXPR ')' OP2
;

OP:     OP1 | OP2 ;

EXPR:   EXPR1
|       ID '=' EXPR

EXPR1:  EXPR2
|       EXPR1 EQ EXPR2
|       EXPR1 LE EXPR2
|       EXPR1 GE EXPR2
|       EXPR1 NE EXPR2
|       EXPR1 '>' EXPR2
|       EXPR1 '<' EXPR2
;

EXPR2: TERM
|       EXPR2 '+' TERM
|       EXPR2 '-' TERM
;

TERM:   VAL
|       TERM '*' VAL
|       TERM '/' VAL
;

VAL:    NUM
|       '-' VAL
|       '!' VAL
|       '(' EXPR ')'
|       ID
|       ID '(' ARGS ')'
;

ARGS:
|       ARG
|       ARGS ',' ARG
;

ARG:    EXPR
|       STRING
;


input: /* empty string */
 | input line
 ;

line: '\n'
 | exp '\n' { System.out.println(" " + $1.dval + " "); }
 ;

exp: NUM { $$ = $1; }
 | exp '+' exp { $$ = new ParserVal($1.dval + $3.dval); }
 | exp '-' exp { $$ = new ParserVal($1.dval - $3.dval); }
 | exp '*' exp { $$ = new ParserVal($1.dval * $3.dval); }
 | exp '/' exp { $$ = new ParserVal($1.dval / $3.dval); }
 | '-' exp %prec NEG { $$ = new ParserVal(-$2.dval); }
 | exp '^' exp { $$ = new ParserVal(Math.pow($1.dval, $3.dval)); }
 | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
 ;
%%

String ins;
StringTokenizer st;

void yyerror(String s)
{
 System.out.println("par:"+s);
}

boolean newline;
int yylex()
{
String s;
int tok;
Double d;
 //System.out.print("yylex ");
 if (!st.hasMoreTokens())
 if (!newline)
 {
 newline=true;
 return '\n'; //So we look like classic YACC example
 }
 else
 return 0;
 s = st.nextToken();
 //System.out.println("tok:"+s);
 try
 {
 d = Double.valueOf(s);/*this may fail*/
 yylval = new ParserVal(d.doubleValue()); //SEE BELOW
 tok = NUM;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
 tok = s.charAt(0);/*if not float, return char*/
 }
 return tok;
}

void dotest()
{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 System.out.println("BYACC/J Calculator Demo");
 System.out.println("Note: Since this example uses the StringTokenizer");
 System.out.println("for simplicity, you will need to separate the items");
 System.out.println("with spaces, i.e.: '( 3 + 5 ) * 2'");
 while (true)
 {
 System.out.print("expression:");
 try
 {
 ins = in.readLine();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
 }
 st = new StringTokenizer(ins);
 newline=false;
 yyparse();
 }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
 Parser par = new Parser(false);
 par.dotest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have TWO independent grammars in your .y file:  `PROGRAM` and `input`.  Since there's no `%start` directive, the first one (`PROGRAM`) is taken as your grammar, and since this grammar never refers to `input` or any of the symbols after it, they are all useless -- they can never be reduced when parsing `PROGRAM`.

You can only have ONE grammar in your file -- delete (or comment out) the unwanted one.

Answer (score 0):

I have forgotten about tail recursion in yacc (OPS), but the following seems a simplification.

```
OPS:    OP RESTOPS
;

RESTOPS: OPS
|      
;

OP:    '{' OPS '}'
|       IF '(' EXPR ')' OP ELSEOP
|       WHILE '(' EXPR ')' OP
|       EXIT ';'
|       EXPR ';'
;

ELSEOP: ELSE OP
|
;
```

Comment: SO and what about EXPR definition?

Comment: I am a bit out of yacc. You are doing deep nesting of nonterminals. As with RESTOPS/ELSEOP I would try RESTEXPR with operator EXPR, or empty.